# PHP getting value from a multi dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, session, multidimensional-array

I have a multi dimensional array that I am able to loop through with a FOR loop and return the values to enter into the database. 
The problem comes in when the user deletes an item which I then take out of the $_SESSION[cart] array using unset. Specifically if it was line 2 in the cart I would use

```
unset($_SESSION[cart][2]);
```

Now I can no longer use the FOR loop because the values I use in the FOR loop have gaps in them.

The original array would be:

`$_SESSION['cart'][1]`
`$_SESSION['cart'][2]`
`$_SESSION['cart'][3]`

AFTER deleting line 2 from the cart(it can be any line this is an example):

`$_SESSION['cart'][1]`
`$_SESSION['cart'][3]`

This is how the array is structured:

```
$_SESSION['cart'][$lineId] = array('stockNumber' => $stockNumber, 'description' => $description, 'masterPrice' => $masterPrice);
```

$lineId is the line item in the cart

I currently retrieve the data from the cart using this loop:

```
for ($i = 1, $howMany = count($_SESSION['cart']); $i < $howMany+1; ) {
$stk_code = $_SESSION['cart'][$i]["stockNumber"];
$description = $_SESSION['cart'][$i]["description"]; 
$unitPrice = $_SESSION['cart'][$i]["masterPrice"];}
```

I need help in understanding this and a way to loop through the array regardless of line item number. I have no way of knowing how many items will be in the cart or how many they take out. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `foreach` perhaps.

Comment: after deleting if you make your $_SESSION['cart'] array to array_values($_SESSION['cart']) and try.... it will re-index your array..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can use foreach instead of for loop

```
$_SESSION['cart'][1] = array('stockNumber' => 1, 'description' => 'test', 'masterPrice' => 115);

    foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $value) {
      $stk_code = $value["stockNumber"];
      $description = $value["description"]; 
      $unitPrice = $value["masterPrice"];
    }
```